# Update project from older CUDA version

Tags: cuda

In my older CUDA project I had the globals:

```
__device__ uint8_t dev_intersect
__constant__ uint8_t dev_flags
```

... and used them this way:

```
cudaGetSymbolAddress((void**)&ptr_dev_intersect,"dev_intersect")
cudaMemcpyToSymbol("dev_flags",&flags,sizeof(flags))
```

Now, since CUDA 5.0 (and newer) the symbols must be passed directly (without string), so I define the globals this way:

```
__device__ uint8_t *dev_intersect
__constant__ uint8_t *dev_flags
```

...and call the functions this way:

```
cudaGetSymbolAddress((void**)&ptr_dev_intersect,dev_intersect)
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dev_flags,&flags,sizeof(flags))
```

Am I doing it right so far? I'm asking you, because when I update the code, I start getting other errors, which makes me kinda suspicious. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching from a POD variable to a pointer is probably not what you want.

If you didn't make changes elsewhere in your code to account for that difference, I would expect things to break.

To update your cuda function calls, leave your variables as-is:

```
__device__ uint8_t dev_intersect;
__constant__ uint8_t dev_flags;
```

And just drop the quotes from your cuda API functions that use those variables:

```
cudaGetSymbolAddress((void**)&ptr_dev_intersect,dev_intersect);
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dev_flags,&flags,sizeof(flags));
```

Here is a complete worked example:

```
$ cat t524.cu
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;

__device__ uint8_t dev_intersect;
__constant__ uint8_t dev_flags;

__global__ void mykernel(uint8_t *d1_ptr){

  printf("data 1 = %c\n", *d1_ptr);
  printf("dev_flags = %c\n", dev_flags);

}

int main(){

  uint8_t *ptr_dev_intersect;
  uint8_t flags = 'X';
  uint8_t dev_intersect_data = 'Y';

  cudaGetSymbolAddress((void**)&ptr_dev_intersect,dev_intersect);
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dev_flags,&flags,sizeof(flags));
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dev_intersect,&dev_intersect_data,sizeof(dev_intersect_data));

  mykernel<<<1,1>>>(ptr_dev_intersect);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  return 0;
}

$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t524 t524.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t524
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
data 1 = Y
dev_flags = X
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Comment: The program runs, yet I'm getting "invalid device symbol error" and the compiler underlines both variables.

Comment: I believe that is a separate issue.  If you want help with the invalid device symbol error, please write a new question and provide a complete code that demonstrates the error.  If you want proof that my answer is correct, I've added a complete worked example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Actually the prog runs fine, just the permanent "invalid device symbol" message bothers me. I'm either not paying attention to it or I'll try to narrow down the issue later today.

Comment: The invalid device symbol message is certainly a problem.  It's not something that can safely be ignored.  The compiler underline may be an intellisense/CUDA issue, and not something that represents a "real" problem.  But without a concrete example, it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: I've overlooked the quotation marks in some part of my code. Now when I removed them it's not complaining anymore. Thanks once again. Feels good to have helping people like you on this website.